# How to benchmark assert statements?

Tags: java, jmh

The next version of [my Design by Contract API](https://github.com/cowwoc/requirements.java/) uses the following syntax:

`assert requireThat(name, value).size().isGreaterThan(3).elseThrowAssert();`

The idea being that the validation only runs if assertions are enabled. I want to time four scenarios:

1. Time an empty method.
2. Time a validation without using assert.
3. Time a validation using assert, with asserts are enabled.
4. Time a validation using assert, with asserts are disabled.

But I'm unsure how to blackhole methods that use asserts...

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
public class GcTest
{
    private String name = "actual";
    private Map<Integer, Integer> value;

    public GcTest()
    {
        value = new HashMap<>(5, 1f);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            value.put(i, 5 - i);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(jvmArgsPrepend = "-da")
    @SuppressWarnings("EmptyMethod")
    public void emptyMethod()
    {
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void requireThat(Blackhole bh)
    {
        bh.consume(DefaultJavaValidators.requireThat(name, value).size().isGreaterThan(3));
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(jvmArgsPrepend = "-da")
    public void assertThatWithAssertionsDisabled(Blackhole bh)
    {
        assert blackholeAssert(bh, DefaultJavaValidators.requireThat(name, value).size().isGreaterThan(3).
            elseThrowAssert());
    }

    private boolean blackholeAssert(Blackhole bh, boolean resultOfAssertion)
    {
        bh.consume(resultOfAssertion);
        return true;
    }


    @Benchmark
    @Fork(jvmArgsPrepend = "-ea")
    public void assertThatWithAssertionsEnabled(Blackhole bh)
    {
        assert blackholeAssert(bh, DefaultJavaValidators.requireThat(name, value).size().isGreaterThan(3).
            elseThrowAssert());
    }
}
```

Does this look correct?

Comment: You don't have to benchmark assertion statements. An assertion statement is equivalent to an `if( static_boolean_variable )` while the code is cold, and becomes absolutely nothing when the code gets hot.  Also, I believe you mean "cont***r***act", not "contact".

Comment: @MikeNakis Typo corrected, thank you. I wanted to benchmark `assert` to prove to myself that assert does not trigger any runtime or memory cost. Sure enough, JMH confirms it. The interpreted code may differ, but the JITed code with and without the assert is probably identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The trick is to define this method:

```
private boolean blackholeAssert(Blackhole bh, boolean resultOfAssertion)
{
    bh.consume(resultOfAssertion);
    return true;
}
```

and invoke it from inside the assert statement:

```
@Benchmark
@Fork(jvmArgsPrepend = "-da")
public void assertThatWithAssertionsDisabled(Blackhole bh)
{
    assert blackholeAssert(bh, DefaultJavaValidators.requireThat(name, value).size().isGreaterThan(3).
        elseThrowAssert());
}
```